# Can't install Xamarin.Firebase.Common on shared Xamarin project

Tags: firebase, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Is the package `Xamarin.Firebase.Common` supposed to be able to get installed on the shared Xamarin project?

I try to install it, but I get an error:

> Error NU1202  Package Xamarin.Firebase.Common 120.1.0.1 is not
> compatible with netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0). Package
> Xamarin.Firebase.Common 120.1.0.1 supports:
>
> - monoandroid12.0 (MonoAndroid,Version=v12.0)
> - net6.0-android31.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0)

Both `Target Framework` and `Target Android Version` are set to `Android 13` for the Android project.

Comment: No, it's not. "Common" is not a description for a shared cross-platform library but means it contains common classes shared by several other nugets for Firebase. You need to install this into your Android project.

Comment: What am I supposed to install to the shared project though? I'm trying to use `FirebaseNetworkException` in my code and it's not recognized. Visual Studio suggests to install `Xamarin.Firebase.Common` to fix the error. I have done that already for the Android project. It's not possible for the Shared project.

Comment: You shouldn't have to deal with that in your shared project, because network exceptions are platform specific. Your Xamarin app is hosted inside a native app and thus doesn't know specifics about the platform it's running on. What exactly are you trying to achieve? What do you think you need `FirebaseNetworkException` for?

Comment: Just to deliver a relevant message to the user.

Comment: More context, please. What are you using Firebase for in your app?

Comment: It's Firebase Authentication. There are other exceptions that are also useful to catch, like `WeakPassword` for example. I also use `Plugin.FirebaseAuth`.

Comment: Firebase auth is implemented differently on Android and iOS, there are separate libraries for each, but there are also cross-platform libraries, such as `Plugin.FirebaseAuth`, which handle the platform specifics under the hood, but they essentially work in the same way. In any case, you cannot catch the exceptions from the platform specific code from within the shared context. The reason is the direction of the dependencies. Platform specific code depends on shared code, not the other way around. `Plugin.FirebaseAuth` defines a `FirebaseAuthException` with an `ErrorType` field you can use.

Comment: You should update your question and explain what you are *actually* trying to accomplish in the question, because currently, the answer to your *current* question simply is: **no**, you cannot install Xamarin.Firebase.Common into the shared project. Don't forget to include the code where you're trying to catch the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you cannot use the `Xamarin.Firebase.Common` package, which has a dependency on Android, in the shared project of your Xamarin.Forms app.

Secondly, you cannot use native exceptions in the shared, cross-platform context. Therefore, you won't have access to `FirebaseNetworkException`, etc. in the shared project.

Instead, since you're already using the [Plugin.FirebaseAuth](https://github.com/f-miyu/Plugin.FirebaseAuth), you need to catch `FirebaseAuthException` instead, which wraps the different platform-specific exceptions and hides them behind error codes.

Your code should be looking something like this:

```cs
try
{
    var provider = new OAuthProvider("google.com");
    var result = await CrossFirebaseAuth.Current.Instance.SignInWithProviderAsync(provider);
}
catch (FirebaseAuthException e)
{
    switch(e.ErrorType)
    {
        case ErrorType.NetWork:
            //handle network error 
            break;
        case InvalidCredentials:
            //handle invalid credentials
            break;
        //...
        default: break;
    }
}
```

There's a full list for the mapping of the `ErrorType` [enum](https://github.com/f-miyu/Plugin.FirebaseAuth/blob/master/Plugin.FirebaseAuth/Shared/ErrorType.cs) to the Firebase exceptions [in the documentation](https://github.com/f-miyu/Plugin.FirebaseAuth#firebaseauthexception-error-types).

Therefore, wherever you need to catch an exception, you can check the `ErrorType` and perform the appropriate operation or show an error message to the user.

Comment: OK. So that's how `ErrorType` can get utilized in the code. Thanks for making it clear!

Answer (score 0):

Just as ewerspej said, you need to install the Xamarin.Firebase.Common pakcage in the xamarin.forms project's android part.

And then, you can create a class in the android part and use the `FirebaseNetworkException` in the class's method. After that, you can use the dependency service to call the method in the shared Xamarin project.

For more information, you can refer to the official document about the [Xamarin.Forms DependencyService Introduction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction).

Comment: I see that `Plugin.FirebaseAuth` has `Error Types`: https://github.com/f-miyu/Plugin.FirebaseAuth#firebaseauthexception-error-types These aren't exceptions, so they can't be used in a try-catch block, right? How can they be used though? They probably can be used in the shared project, so there is no need for utilizing the `Dependency Service`.